# Want to hide the application from the app drawer and want to open the from another app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want the app to be hidden in the app drawer and will access the app through another app... it's like a supporting app for my main app... my main app can only access the supporting app and the supporting app cannot work without the main app...

So want to hide the supporting app from the app drawer so that only my main app can use it and will not fill the users app drawer...

I actually have no idea what I can do for this.

Want to hide the supporting app from the app drawer so that only my main app can use it and will not fill the users app drawer...

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, find the `<intent-filter>` that looks like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

That says "put this activity in the app drawer". If you do not want the activity in the app drawer, remove that `<intent-filter>`.

Note that any activities that you want the other app to be able to start will need either an `<intent-filter>` or `android:exported="true"`.

Comment: If I remove the <intent-filter>  then it shows the "Error running 'app':Default Activity not found"

So what do I need to do that?

Comment: @GaganKumar: By default, Android Studio starts up your launcher activity, and you no longer have one. You will need to edit the run configuration (Run > Edit Configurations from the main menu) and change the "Launch Options" to "Specified Activity", then indicate what activity should be run.